# Installing scons in macosx

Tags: macos, scons

I have downloaded latest scons-local and tried to install it using cmd

```
sudo python scons.py install
```

But I get error

```
scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "/Users/Krupa/wrtc/scons-local-2.3.0/scons-local-2.3.0/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 905, in _main
```

Answer (score 0):

The scons-local package is not meant to be installed.  It's meant to be run in place.

The non -local package is meant to be installed, and it has a setup.py which you run to install.